# Associated (dynamic) Scopes not working until I made any change in register file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have two models, restaurant and cuisine with a many to many association. And I have this in my app/admin/restaurant.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Restaurant do
  scope("All"){|scope| scope.order("created_at desc")}
  Cuisine.all.each do |c|
    scope(c.name) { |scope| scope.joins(:cuisines).where("cuisines.id=?",c.id)}
  end
end
```

The problem is whenever I delete or add a new cuisine the scopes do not change until I make a change to my admin/restaurant.rb file. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding in my admin/restaurant.rb

```
controller do
  before_filter :update_scopes, :only => :index
  def update_scopes
    resource = active_admin_config

    Cuisine.order("created_at ASC").each do |m|
      next if resource.scopes.any? { |scope| scope.name == m.name}
      resource.scopes << (ActiveAdmin::Scope.new m.name do |restaurants|
        restaurants.joins(:cuisines).where("cuisines.id=?", m.id)
      end)
    end

    resource.scopes.delete_if do |scope|
      !(Cuisine.all.any? { |m| scope.name == m.name })
    end
    resource.scopes.unshift(ActiveAdmin::Scope.new "All" do |restaurants| restaurants end)
  end
```

found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450905/active-admin-scopes-for-each-instance-of-a-related-model)

Comment: Nice job searching for a solution. Didn't realize scopes was array-like. What happens if someone adds a cuisine named "all"? Fortunately, Rails will throw an error and not overwrite the default `Restaurant.all`.

Answer (score 1):

---

I'm not sure of a way to defines scopes dynamically, at least using the `scope` method.

The alternative to the `scope` method is defining a class method, which accomplishes the same thing so far as I know.

In other words,

```
scope("All"){|scope| scope.order("created_at desc")}
```

is the same as

```
# in a Class

class << self
  def All
    order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

You can dynamically create class methods using this method (taken from [ruby-defining-class-methods](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html):

```
class Object
  def meta_def name, &blk
    (class << self; self; end).instance_eval { define_method name.to_s, &blk }
  end
end
```

I'll use the following to remove the generated class methods:

```
class Object
      def meta_undef name
        (class << self; self; end).class_eval { remove_method name.to_sym }
      end
end
```

These methods can be called from the `save` and `destroy` hooks on your models, i.e.:

```
# in a Model
def save(*args)
  self.class.meta_def(name) do 
    joins(:cuisines).where("cuisines.id=?",c.id)
  end
  super(*args)
end

def destroy(*args)
  self.class.meta_undef(name)
  super(*args)
end
```

Then whenever a record is created or removed, the scopes will be updated. There are pros and cons of this approach. Clearly it's nice to define methods on the fly, but **this is vulnerable to remote code execution**.

Personally I'd probably hold off from dynamically defining class methods (i.e. scopes) and just make one that accepts an argument. Example:

```
  # This is with standard ActiveRecord, not sure about ActiveAdmin
  class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.All
      order("created_at desc")
    end
  end
  class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.by_name(name)
      Restaurant.all.joins(:cuisines).where("cuisines.name=?", name)
    end
  end

  Cuisine.by_name("something")
  Restaurant.all.All
  Restaurant.All
```

---

**edit** in response to your comment:

`load(file)` will re-load the source. So you could try the following:

```
# in a model
def save(*args)
  load(Rails.root.join("app", "models", "THIS_MODEL_FILE.rb")
  super
end

def destroy(*args)
  load(Rails.root.join("app", "models", "THIS_MODEL_FILE.rb")
  super
end
```

Under the hood, `save` is called for both create and update. So overriding it and `destroy` covers all the CRUD operations.

The reason I didn't initially recommend this approach is that I haven't personally used it. I'd be curious to know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply there is on more thing whenever I make change in admin/restaurant.rb file the new cuisine shown up can we reload the register file whenever any cuisine changes.

Comment: OK @AsnadAtta, I've added a response in my answer. Please see the edit at the end of the post.